# Convert string into new data structure and back into string

Tags: haskell, converters

I'm trying to create a new data structure BigNumber with 2 arguments: a char with '+' Or '-' to differentiate between positive and negative numbers and a list of the number's digits. And use this in 2 functions: scanner that converts a string into a BigNumber and output that converts a BigNumber into a string.
This is what I have so far:

```
data BigNumber = Char [Integer]
   
-- Verifies if the number is positive or negative and returns its correspondent char 
scanner_Sign :: Char -> Char
scanner_Sign s = if s == '-' then '-' else '+'

-- Converts string into list of digits (without signal)                
scanner_Numbers :: (Char, String) -> [Integer]
scanner_Numbers (sign, s) 
                | sign == '+' = map (read . (:"")) s :: [Integer]
                | sign == '-' = map (read . (:"")) (tail s) :: [Integer]

scanner :: String -> BigNumber
scanner = scanner_Numbers (s, n)
          where scanner_Sign (head s)

output :: BigNumber -> String
output (sign, numbers)
       | sign == '+' = show numbers
       | sign == '-' = - (show numbers)
       where (BigNumber (sign, numbers))
```

Both the aux functions for scanner are working but I don't know how to use them in the main. And I'm still clueless regarding the output function...
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `data BigNumber = Char [Integer]` doesn't mean what you think it means. It defines a type `BigNumber` that has a single constructor named `Char` (no relation to the standard type `Char`), and that constructor wraps a list of `Integer`s.

Comment: And the rest of your code is also pretty nonsensical. I would recommend to start with making sure you understand exactly what each piece of your code actually means, and what you expect it to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a new data structure BigNumber with 2 arguments:

This `data BigNumber = Char [Integer]` creates a new datatype with a Constructor named `Char` and only one argument. So either create a new datatype like this:

```
data BigNumber = BigNumber Char [Integer]
```

and adapt your functions accordingly, or you can mostly keep your `output` function with

```
type BigNumber = (Char, [Integer])
```

By the way, `Integer`s in haskell already support arbitrary large (and negative) numbers. You might use `Int` instead.

> Both the aux functions for scanner are working

"working" as in "compiling"? It seems you want

```
scanner_Numbers ('-', "1234") == [2,3,4]
```

This drops the "1". Hm, because you want to repeat the first character, i.e. call `scanner_Numbers ('-', "-567")`. This is unnecessary. You can just do

```
 scanner ('-':s) = BigNumber '-' that-map-read-stuff-with-s
 scanner s       = BigNumber '+' that-map-read-stuff-with-s
```

Your syntax for `where`-clauses is off. You need definitions there, i.e. they have a `=` sign just like the top level functions.

regarding output:

```
   | sign == '-' = - (show numbers)
```

Does not compile. `show` has a signature, roughly `show :: whatever -> String`. So it returns a `String` and you try to negate a String. `-`is not an operation on Strings! Fortunately, `:` is an operation on Strings, so try to put a character representing your minus there.
Seriously, try to understand what I just wrote before unmasking the spoiler.

> `| sign == '-' = '-' : (show numbers)`

Then you will find out `show numbers` does not produce the pretty output you want. Hint: something like you did when converting from String to BigNumber, just the other way round.

Comment: Thanks, it help a lot. And sorry, my question must have sounded kind of dumb. I've been learning for just a couple week, I'll get better.